# Cross platform mobile 3d engine

Tags: mobile, 3d, cross-platform

Does anyone know of any production-ready (preferred) or beta-quality 3d engine for mobile platforms?

It ideally should support a 3d acceleration on device if available.

We looking for renderer only, as the engine required for non-gaming purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oolong Engine is written in C++ with some help from Objective-C. It will help you to create new games and port existing games to the iPhone, the iPod touch and the iPad.
http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/